# How to get a Serilog logger as Microsoft logger in a console application for DI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I need to get Serilog as a logger in the console application in order to then pass it to the class. I know how to do this in ASP.NET Core, but I don't understand how to do it in a console application. `var loggerService = host.Services.GetService<ILogger>()` returns null.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyProgram.Services;
using Serilog;

var hostBuilder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
hostBuilder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostBuilder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();

hostBuilder.Logging.ClearProviders();
hostBuilder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
hostBuilder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var host = hostBuilder.Build();

var configService = host.Services.GetService<IConfiguration>();
var loggerService = host.Services.GetService<ILogger>(); // null

IMyService myService = new MyService(configService, loggerService);
```

The code of the class:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyService(IConfiguration config, ILogger logger)
    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        _logger.LogError("Exceprion.");
    }
}
```

Comment: try logger = host.Services.GetService<ILogger<MyService>();

Comment: Use the DI to create `MyService`, then you don't need all the extra GetService() calls to get the parameters., Just one to create the thing, which will also work in the future in case other parameters are needed.